# polymorphic lists in ML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have this snippet of the code in ML:

```
local

fun unfolder( [] , n ) = []
    | unfolder( l::ls, n ) = (n, l) :: unfolder( ls, n )

in

fun flat list = unfolder(list, 1)  

end;
```

it gives me an error:

```
unexpected exception (bug?) in SML/NJ: EA [EA]
  raised at: ../../MLRISC/x86/mltree/x86.sml:417.32-417.34
             ../compiler/Basics/stats/stats.sml:198.40
             ../compiler/Basics/stats/stats.sml:198.40
             ../compiler/Basics/stats/stats.sml:198.40
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
```

but when I change `its (n, l) to (n, l:int)` it works, and when to `(n, l:'a)`, can somebody please explain why polymorphic type doesn't work, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an internal bug in SML/NJ. The program works flawlessly if compiled with MLton, adding:

```
val _ =
  let val l = flat [1,2,3]
      fun printer (a,b) = Int.toString(a) ^ ", " ^ Int.toString(b)
  in
    print (printer (hd l) ^ "\n")
  end
```

Report it. Your example seem digestible in size - and probably has to do with polymorphism representation.